# OutOfMemoryException in Async socket server

Tags: c#, sockets, async-await, cancellationtokensource

I am writing socket server program. which will listen to the particular IP and Port. once the data come in it process the data and store it in the database. 
I want my program to listen 24*7 whether data comes in or not. if comes then process it otherwise wait until new client joins

Here is the sample code

```
static async Task AcceptClientsAsync(TcpListener listener, CancellationToken ct)
{
            try
            {
                var clientCounter = 0;
                while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
                    clientCounter++;
                    EchoAsync(client, clientCounter, ct);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                NewLog.WriteErrorLogToBuffer("exception in AcceptClientsAsync " + e.InnerException, false);
            }

}
```

it is working fine but I'm getting out of memory exception after some time. is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TcpClient` instances are never disposed, so they will remain open until your program goes out of memory and closed by the OS.

You need to close the `TcpClient` after you finished using it. The best way to do this is by wrapping it inside a `using` block:

```
using(TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(true))
{
    clientCounter++;
    EchoAsync(client, clientCounter, ct);
}
```

An alternative is to manually closing it using its `Close()` method, but be aware that if an exception is thrown before the call to `Close()` your `TcpClient` will remain open forever.